# What older regulations and exemptions does Boeing's 737 line benefit from?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations, safety, boeing-737, regulations

Boeing is occasionally [accused in the press](https://www.nolan-law.com/blog/2021/02/jammed-elevators-the-result-of-a-grandfathered-design/) of keeping the 737 competitive by being able to avoid newer regulations and standards, either through being previously certified or by other means.

The oldest example I've seen is an exemption from [FAA amendment on 2-second V1 margin](https://www.flightglobal.com/airbus-challenges-737-grandfather-allowance/16468.article) for the 737-700 back in 1995, and the newest is Boeing's [engine anti-ice exemption request for the MAX 7](https://www.dallasnews.com/business/airlines/2024/01/05/boeing-wants-faa-to-exempt-max-7-from-safety-rules-to-get-it-in-the-air/), which has since been dropped.

What differences between 1967 and 2024 regulations does Boeing's 737 line still benefit from, which wouldn't always apply to a new airplane of similar size and role?